# My macbook pro 13' 2015 keyboard and track pad not working

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad

Suddenly the keyboard and trackpad of my macbook pro 13' 2015 model stopped working, this issue happened when I upgrade from sierra to high sierra. Also I already tried re-installing the OS from the internet recovery way, still the issue is present. Then I tried booting my macbook pro on Remix OS (android) both the keyboard and trackpad is working fine.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you boot into Safe Mode (hold shift while booting)?

Comment: This looks like a hardware problem amplified by a software change in driver timeouts. None of the advised resets will be of any help. Please read this excellent answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/246403/22003

Comment: Your excellent test with another OS proves there is a software component of the problem. Test with an external USB keyboard to check for a hardware component of the problem. Beware: some software changes may exhibit poor quality hardware behaviour.

Comment: @danielAzuelos I tried using wired and bluetooth keyboard and mouse, they are working fine

Comment: @Allan yah tried Safe Mode but still it's not working also

Comment: Test it with other USB devices.  This will help narrow it down to the USB bus or the keyboard/trackpad.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend resetting the SMC and the NVRAM (PRAM) 1st and see if they help get the keyboard and/or the trackpad working again.

Since they work on Remix OS it could also be a software issue, after you reset the SMC and NVRAM if neither starts working then try safe mode. If it doesnt work in safe mode (safe boot) then try with another user account. If the same results then you'll need to backup your Mac and then reinstall MacOS.

If it still persists afterwards than it may be a connection error, you'll need to take it to the Apple Store.

But do everything else 1st.

Comment: Already tried the SMC, NVRAM and safe mode...still having the problem. I think i'll try reinstall macOS

Comment: Ok, keep me posted. did you try with a new user yet?

Comment: tried also the other user still the same, Also tried to load El Capitan on a external USB, also still not working, I think I will just bring this on Apple store